# Affinity propagation fit, fit_predict and predict methods

Tags: python, data-mining, scikit-learn

I am using sklearn affinity propagation algorithm as below.

```
affprop = sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation(affinity="precomputed", damping=0.5)
```

I also have a similarity matrix created for the data I am using. Now I want to use my similarity matrix to use in the affinity propagation model.

In [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html) they have different methods for this such as fit, fit_predict, predict. So, I'm not sure what to use.

Is it correct if I use,

```
affprop.fit(my similarity matrix)
```

Comment: For people who downvote please tell me what's wrong in this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct to use as you indicated.

For example, in below , I use levenshtein for make similarity matrix. then use this matrix for clustring by affinity algorithm.

```
lev_similarity = -1*np.array([[distance.levenshtein(w1,w2) for w1 in words]
                              for w2 in words])

af = affprop.fit(lev_similarity)
```